# Upgrading Python on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to upgrade my python to 2.7.11 on Ubuntu 15.10, by following the guides here

http://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-ubuntu-and-linuxmint/

http://mbless.de/blog/2016/01/09/upgrade-to-python-2711-on-ubuntu-1404-lts.html

But after, when I try and reopen terminal, and type in `python` it still shows the version is 2.7.10

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

The post you've linked says explicitly in the first sentence: *"you should not touch the Python version of the system."* i.e., `/usr/bin/python` should remain the same and therefore if `/usr/bin` is earlier in your `$PATH` envvar than the path to the newly installed python version then `python` invokes `/usr/bin/python` and you see the old version.

To install/manage multiple minor python versions, you could use [`pythonz`](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz) or similar tools (such as [`pyenv`](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv)):

```
$ pythonz install 2.7.11    # to install 2.7.11 version
$ $(pythonz locate 2.7.11)  # to start the corresponding version
```

You could create a virtualenv using the desired python version (using [`virtualenvwrapper`'s](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) command):

```
$ mkvirtualenv -p $(pythonz locate 2.7.11) py2.7.11
```

`python` will refer to 2.7.11 version inside the virtual environment.